# dropzonejs rotates the picture on mobile

Tags: javascript, image, jquery-mobile, upload, dropzone.js

Briefly,

I'm using dropzone.js for one of my projects and I've realized dropzonejs just ignores a vertical photo taken with a mobile phone.

On desktop, there is no problem but when you try to open the [original sample](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) and use the uploader with your mobile phone (tested with Android and iOS) you will see the image is rotated.

How can I prevent this to happen?

Best,

Comment: I had this same thing happen.  I had to fix it with PHP.. what backend language are you using?

Comment: I'm using Meteor.js. So, JavaScript, Node.js.... But I would like to fix it on front end since I'm sending the photo directly to a 3rd party software on front end and getting results back. I mean, I'm expecting dozens of images  in an hour in my system so I really really don't want to do it with backend rotate..

Comment: What I did to fix it in PHP is a I research what was called EXIF data.  Maybe you can google it and try and find a javascript solution to read in EXIF

Comment: I used same kinda trick on my server, unfortunately.